# PHP session ID changes every request

Tags: php, session

I know there's a lot of similar questions, and I've been spending days trying to look up the solution but am still unable to solve it, so here I am.
It seems like the session ID changes on every request (between pages, on every refresh, etc). The session variables didn't seem to persist to the next page, so I tried to grab the session ID (tried printing & using Live HTTP Headers add-on on FF), and it is different each time.

The thing is, it was working about a year ago before I temporarily abandoned the project, but when I tried to get back to it, it is not working anymore. I even tried creating a very simple page that just prints the session variable set on the previous page, and still no luck. I made sure nothing gets printed before `session_start()`, checked the permission on the path stored in `session.save_path`, but can't figure out why it is still generating a new session ID on each request. I am suspecting something with the configuration, but can't put my hands on what it might be.

Here are the simple pages I used for testing:

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

  $_SESSION['hello'] = "TESTING";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello!
  <a href="testing.php">click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

testing.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo session_id();
print "\nHello, ";
print $_SESSION['hello'];
?>
```

This is what I see on the Live HTTP Headers:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=some_id; path=/; domain=.DOMAIN.EXT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

I see that the cookie is set to expire instantly - could that be it? If it is, what do I need to do to fix that?

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: run `phpinfo()` and check the session settings

Comment: Try putting `session_write_close()` at the end of script.

Comment: @MichałPrzybyłowicz That still didn't do it :( Thanks though!

Comment: @Dagon I'm not really sure what to look for in them, but I'll see what I can make out of that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this before session_start ?

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60); // expires in 30 minutes
```

Comment: Just tried it, and still the same thing :( Thanks though!

Comment: no character at the start of your file before you put this ? This really has to be the first thing in your file
     <?php
     session_start();

Comment: Yes, I checked multiple times to make sure there's nothing before session_start()..